# Is there a way to set a default value (for example based on IOptions) to ignored property when configuring entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a property on my entity, that does not exist in the database, so during entity configuration, I ignore it:

```
builder.Ignore(m => m.MaxDeliveryAttempts);
```

However I need this property to be by default set to a value I get from my appsettings.json file.

I can get `IOptions` injected into by DbContext, but I cannot figure out how to force EF to set the value of `MaxDeliveryAttempts` from settings when it instantiates the entity.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the default value. For example:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(b => b.Rating)
        .HasDefaultValue(3);
}
```

Reference: [Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#default-values)

Comment: I tried that, but this column does not exist in the Db and I get SqlException: Invalid column name "MaxDeliveryAttempts". That is why I am using Ignore(m => m.MaxDeliveryAttempts) now.

Comment: @mikeyy yeah this would only work if the column existed in the DB. It sounds like you want to get/set this property at runtime but not persist it? (maybe for serialization or something) If that's the case, you would instead inject the `IOptions` wherever you are instantiating the class and set the property there. (Anything inside the `DbContext` class is only concerned with data persistence)

Comment: The thing is the only place I instantiate it is while obtaining it from the DB. The records are inserted by a different system. So the value has to be set somewhere after getting the data from the database. If I won't be able to resolve this problem when configuring the entity, I will probably try the ChangeTracker event or maybe use the repository.

Comment: @mikeyy I see. Starting with EF Core 3.0, you can now intercept database operations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#interception-of-database-operations). You can see how to manipulate results here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception#result-handling. That might work better for you

Comment: Wow, this is really hacky way of achieving my goal. It is interesting to know that such a solution exist, but...I think I will just go ahead and do that from a repository. At least it will be debuggable, but altering an sql statement (which I am normally perfectly fine with) will be only obvious to me and God forbid if I forget about it and have to debug this abomination in a year (what is the most likely scenario, since requirements change is a sure thing). Anyway, thanks. I will maybe open an issue in EF Core github repo or wait for ObjectMaterialized event or service injection into entities